# How to deploy PostgreSQL schema to Google Cloud SQL database using Pulumi?

Tags: database, postgresql, devops, pulumi

I'm trying to initialize a managed PostgreSQL database using Pulumi. The PostgreSQL server itself is hosted and managed by Google Cloud SQL, but I set it up using Pulumi.

I can successfully create the database, but **I'm stumped how to actually initialize it** with my schemas, users, tables, etc. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

I believe I need to use the [Postgres provider](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/postgresql/), similar to what they do for MySQL in [this](https://www.pulumi.com/blog/deploying-mysql-schemas-using-dynamic-providers/) tutorial or [this](https://www.reillywood.com/blog/pulumi-postgres/) example. The below code shows what I have so far:

```py
# Create database resource on Google Cloud
instance = sql.DatabaseInstance(  # This works
    "db-instance",
    name="db-instance",
    database_version="POSTGRES_12",
    region="europe-west4",
    project=project,
    settings=sql.DatabaseInstanceSettingsArgs(
        tier="db-g1-small",  # Or: db-n1-standard-4
        activation_policy="ALWAYS",
        availability_type="REGIONAL",
        backup_configuration={
            "enabled": True,
        }
    ),
    deletion_protection=False,
)

database = sql.Database(  # This works as well
    "db",
    name="db",
    instance=instance.name,
    project=project,
    charset="UTF-8",
)

# The below should create a table such as 
#     CREATE TABLE users (id uuid, email varchar(255), api_key varchar(255);
# How to tell it to use this SQL script?
# How to connect it to the above created PostgreSQL resource?
postgres = pg.Database(  # This doesn't work
    f"users",
    name="users",
    is_template=False,
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [sample code](https://github.com/tusharshahrs/pulumi-homelab/tree/master/gcp-postgres-py) with an explanation on how we set everything up including create/delete table with Pulumi.

The code will look like this:

```
# Postgres https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/postgresql/
# provider: https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/postgresql/provider/
postgres_provider = postgres.Provider("postgres-provider",
  host=myinstance.public_ip_address,
  username=users.name,
  password=users.password,
  port=5432,
  superuser=True)

# creates a database on the instance in google cloud with the provider we created
mydatabase = postgres.Database("pulumi-votes-database",
   encoding="UTF8",
   opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(provider=postgres_provider)
)

# Table creation/deletion is via pg8000 https://github.com/tlocke/pg8000
def tablecreation(mytable_name):
    print("tablecreation with:", mytable_name)
    create_first_part = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
    create_sql_querty = "(id serial PRIMARY KEY, email VARCHAR ( 255 ) UNIQUE NOT NULL, api_key VARCHAR ( 255 ) NOT NULL)"
    create_combined = f'{create_first_part} {mytable_name}{create_sql_querty}'
    print("tablecreation create_combined_sql:", create_combined)
    myconnection=pg8000.native.Connection(
        host=postgres_sql_instance_public_ip_address,
        port=5432,
        user=postgres_sql_user_username,
        password=postgres_sql_user_password,
        database=postgres_sql_database_name
    )

    print("tablecreation starting")
    cursor=myconnection.run(create_combined)
    print("Table Created:", mytable_name)
    selectversion = 'SELECT version();'
    cursor2=myconnection.run(selectversion)
    print("SELECT Version:", cursor2)

def droptable(table_to_drop):
    first_part_of_drop= "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
    last_part_of_drop= ' CASCADE'
    combinedstring = f'{first_part_of_drop} {table_to_drop} {last_part_of_drop}'
    conn=pg8000.native.Connection(
        host=postgres_sql_instance_public_ip_address,
        port=5432,
        user=postgres_sql_user_username,
        password=postgres_sql_user_password,
        database=postgres_sql_database_name
        )
    print("droptable delete_combined_sql ", combinedstring)
    cursor=conn.run(combinedstring)
    print("droptable completed ", cursor)
```

After the 1st time of bringing the infrastructure up via `pulumi up -y`, you can uncomment the following code block in `__main__.py` and then add the configs for the postgressql server via cli and then run `pulumi up -y`

```
create_table1 = "votertable"
creating_table = tablecreation(create_table1)
print("")
create_table2 = "regionals"
creating_table = tablecreation(create_table2)
print("")
drop_table = "table2"
deleting_table = droptable(drop_table)
```

The settings for the table are in the `Pulumi.dev.yaml` file and are set via [pulumi config set](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/cli/pulumi_config_set/)

Comment: Oh man, exactly what I needed, thanks a lot! I realize the I'm nitpicking, but could you say a few words about why you recommend commenting/uncommenting table creation? Doesn't that go against infrastructure-as-code ideas?

Comment: Currently, there is no createtable in [gcp](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/gcp/sql/) or [postgres](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/postgresql/) for us to call so we had to so via pg8000. The [outputs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/inputs-outputs/#inputs-and-outputs) from the resources are of type `Output<T>` and the pg8000 requires strings, so we pass the values we need back as configs.